# How to set up the browser scrollbar to scroll part of a page and hide overflow of container div?

Tags: html, cross-browser, scroll, overflow, fixed

I have a fixed header, footer, sidebar on a webpage and I want to set it up so ONLY my content div scrolls with the browser scrollbar. The problem I am experiencing is as follows:

Because my header in made up of **transparent elements** the scrolling text shows behind my header. How do I hide the scrolling text so that it is only visible within the fixed container div that wraps it?

I would like to solve this problem using css only! If possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set your header and footer parent divs (or other block elements) as `position: fixed`

Comment: Your markup doesn't really make this a simple task.  Check out this link to see how you can make a cross-browser fixed header/footer with scrollable content:  http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/basics2.html